# Using web3 v1 beta from Nodejs to invoke myMethod.send() gives use Trusted Signer. How do I do that?

Tags: web3js, parity, raw-transaction

Using `web3` version 1 beta 27, connected to a remote Parity node that's connected to the Ropsten network.

I have created an account with public and private keys, I have sent some test Eth to that address.  That all works fine.

Now trying to actually invoke a function on my contract I get the message

`Your account is locked. Unlock the account via CLI, personal_unlockAccount or use Trusted Signer`

I don't have access to the node via CLI so need to `use Trusted Signer`.

Looking at the docs for [`web3.eth.accounts.sign`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) I see the following

### sign

```
web3.eth.accounts.sign(data, privateKey);
```

Signs arbitrary data. This data is before UTF-8 HEX decoded and enveloped as follows: `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message`.

### Parameters

1. `data - String`: The data to sign. If its a string it will be
2. `privateKey - String`: The private key to sign with.

which quite frankly doesn't make any sense.

Assuming the function I am calling is

```
TestContract.methods.test(testAddress).send()
```

How exactly do I use `web3.eth.accounts.sign` in this context?

Answer (score 2):

I've worked this out now.  First up I need to ensure I have access to the private key for the address, as well as the sender's address.

Given that information I can do the following.

```
const testFn = TestContract.methods.test(testAddress)
const gas = await testFn.estimateGas()
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY)
const data = testFn.encodeABI()
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS, 'pending')
const payload = {
  nonce,
  data,
  gas,
  from: SENDER_ADDRESS,
  to: testContractAddress
}
const signedTx = await account.signTransaction(payload, account.privateKey)
const { rawTransaction } = signedTx
const response = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTransaction)
```

This works fine.

Obviously this is only suitable for code running in NodeJS as you never want the private key to be exposed in a public web interface.